# Need Minimum Textures required for OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Quick question, what is the minimum amount of textures that can be bound for the fragment shader that a OpenGL implementation is required to have?

**Note:**
I would like to know this for OpenGL 1.5, for OpenGL 2.0, and OpenGL 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL 1.x and 2.x require at least 2 texture units. OpenGL 3.x and 4.x require at least 16. Most current GPUs have 32.

You can find those values fairly easily in the OpenGL specification itself, in the "Implementation Dependent Values" table. This specific value is called `MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS` in 1.x and 2.x and `MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` in 3.x and 4.x.